# Cloud Foundry Maven Plugin proxy with authentication

Tags: maven-3, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I am trying to deploy to Pivotal Web Services using the Cloud Foundry maven plugin.  I can deploy very easily with no network proxy in use, but when behind the network proxy I am unsure how to configure the plugin and I was not able to find a good answer while searching online.  Thank you for any help!

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
    <artifactId>cf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>https://api.run.pivotal.io</target>
        <server>cloud-foundry-credentials</server>
        <org>MindWaveService</org>
        <space>development</space>
        <appname>MindwaveServiceApp</appname>
        <url>http://appurl-service.cfapps.io/</url>
        <memory>512</memory>
        <instances>1</instances>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>*</protocol>
  <username>myUsername</username>
  <password>myPass</password>
  <host>myHostUrl</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>153.2.128.54|153.2.204.21|com.ups.*|10.244.223.27</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Please leave all your proxy configuration on your maven settings.xml file. This will take care of Authentication issues.

Comment: I have the proxy configured in my settings.xml file already, but I keep receiving unknown host exceptions.  I'm beginning to suspect its related to: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/479